# Issue handling with MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, error-handling, triggers

This is my trigger for show error handling :

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER NOTA_PENJUALAN_INS BEFORE INSERT ON nota_penjualan FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
DECLARE VDATE DATETIME;

 If (NEW.INVENTORY_OUT_ID IS NOT  NULL) then

 CALL STATUS_INV_OUT(NEW.INVENTORY_OUT_ID);
 SELECT (a.DOCUMENT_DATE) INTO VDATE 
 FROM inventory_out a 
 INNER JOIN NOTA_PENJUALAN b ON a.INVENTORY_OUT_ID=b.INVENTORY_OUT_ID
 WHERE b.NOTA_PENJUALAN_ID=NEW.NOTA_PENJUALAN_ID;
 End IF;

IF(VDATE > NEW.DOCUMENT_DATE) THEN   
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
 SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'sorry can not exceed the date that has been specified';
END IF; 
END
//
```

It displays:

[image]

And does not display my ShowMessage.

Comment: can you change the first line to `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS NOTA_PENJUALAN_INS; DELIMITER //` ...... then at the end do a `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: already, but the error is not of delimitter, and i can create trigger bcasuse sqlstate

Comment: it is not spelled delimitter

Comment: not a matter of delimiter

Comment: What is the version of your mysql server?

Comment: i use mysql 5.5

Comment: sorry my version is still 5.0